# how to substring a value from email address with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to substring the first letter of the first name and the whole second name from email address in XSLT. Not sure if I have to substring then use concat function or how to do it as I don't know the standard length of the email characters.

Input: eman.ahmed@yahoo.com

Desired output: eahmed

<xsl:value-of select="ws:Additional_Information/ws:User_Name_Of_Employee/text()"/>

Should it be something like:
<xsl:value-of select="substring(ws:Additional_Information/ws:User_Name_Of_Manager/text(),1,1,.....)"/>

Thanks for your support!

Comment: 1. Will there always be exactly one period, between first and last name? 2. Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k,   1. Yes.  2. Yes as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way you could look at it is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(input, 1, 1)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(input, '.')"/>
```

In XSLT 2.0 you can do it with regex:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(input, '^(.).*?\.(.*?)$', '$1$2')"/>
```